# How can I execute multiple prepared SQL statements from a single input button press in php?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update, prepared-statement, sql-insert

Context: The page is for menu item entry into an order. When a menu item button is pressed, data from 'theProducts' table is queried and inserted into 'theOrderItems' table. I also want the same button press to take the serving size value (theProducts.dbProdServing) and subtract that amount from the product's inventory (theInventory.dbInventoryAmt), and update that table accordingly.

The problem I'm having is trying to figure out how to have one button press execute two prepared statements with bound values at the same time, those being the statement that INSERTS product data into 'theOrderItems' table and the statement that UPDATEs 'theInventory' table.

Currently, the page runs the INSERT statement fine, but the UPDATE statement doesn't run at all.

There are three pages that handle the entire order system, 'insertOrder.php' opens the order, 'insertOrderItem.php' allows the adding of items to a specific order, and 'completeorder.php' just displays the total order. I'll only post the first two pages.

**insertOrder.php**

```
<?php
$pagetitle = 'Insert Order';
require_once 'header.php';
require_once 'connect.php';

$errormsg = "";
$showform = 1;

$sqlselectt = "SELECT * from theTables";
$resultt = $db->prepare($sqlselectt);
$resultt->execute();

$sqlselectc = "SELECT * from theCustomers";
$resultc = $db->prepare($sqlselectc);
$resultc->execute();

$sqlselects = "SELECT * from theStaff";
$results = $db->prepare($sqlselects);
$results->execute();

$sqlselectl = "SELECT * from theLocations";
$resultl = $db->prepare($sqlselectl);
$resultl->execute();

    if( isset($_POST['thesubmit']) )
    {
        $formfield['ffOrderPickup'] = $_POST['orderPickup'];            
        $formfield['ffCustKey'] = $_POST['custKey'];
        $formfield['ffTableKey'] = $_POST['tableKey'];
        $formfield['ffStaffKey'] = $_POST['staffKey'];
        $formfield['ffLocationKey'] = $_POST['locationKey'];
        $formfield['ffOrderDate'] = $_POST['orderDate'];
        $formfield['ffOrderTime'] = $_POST['orderTime'];

        if(empty($formfield['ffCustKey'])){$errormsg .= "<p>The customer field is empty.</p>";}
        if(empty($formfield['ffTableKey'])){$errormsg .= "<p>The table field is empty.</p>";}
        if(empty($formfield['ffStaffKey'])){$errormsg .= "<p>The employee field is empty.</p>";}
        if(empty($formfield['ffLocationKey'])){$errormsg .= "<p>The location field is empty.</p>";}
        if(empty($formfield['ffOrderDate'])) {$errormsg .= "<p>The order entry date is not selected.</p>"; }
        if(empty($formfield['ffOrderTime'])) {$errormsg .= "<p>The order entry time is not selected.</p>"; }

        if($errormsg != "")
        {
            echo "<div class='error'><p>THERE ARE ERRORS!</p>";
            echo $errormsg;
            echo "</div>";
        }
        else
        {
            $sqlmax = "SELECT MAX(dbOrderKey) AS maxKey FROM theOrders";
            $resultmax = $db->prepare($sqlmax);
            $resultmax->execute();
            $rowmax = $resultmax->fetch();
            $maxKey = $rowmax['maxKey'];
            $maxKey = $maxKey + 1;

            try
            {
                $sqlinsert = 'INSERT INTO theOrders (dbOrderKey, dbCustKey, dbTableKey, dbStaffKey, dbLocationKey, dbOrderComplete, dbOrderDate, dbOrderTime, dbOrderMade, dbOrderPickup)
                              VALUES (:bvOrderKey, :bvCustKey, :bvTableKey, :bvStaffKey, :bvLocationKey, 0, :bvOrderDate, :bvOrderTime, 0, :bvOrderPickup)';
                $stmtinsert = $db->prepare($sqlinsert);
                $stmtinsert->bindvalue(':bvOrderKey', $maxKey);
                $stmtinsert->bindvalue(':bvCustKey', $formfield['ffCustKey']);
                $stmtinsert->bindvalue(':bvTableKey', $formfield['ffTableKey']);
                $stmtinsert->bindvalue(':bvStaffKey', $formfield['ffStaffKey']);
                $stmtinsert->bindvalue(':bvLocationKey', $formfield['ffLocationKey']);
                $stmtinsert->bindvalue(':bvOrderDate', $formfield['ffOrderDate']);
                $stmtinsert->bindvalue(':bvOrderTime', $formfield['ffOrderTime']);
                $stmtinsert->bindvalue(':bvOrderPickup', $formfield['ffOrderPickup']);
                $stmtinsert->execute();

                echo "<p>Order Number: " . $maxKey . "</p>";
                echo "<p>Location: " . $formfield['ffLocationKey'] . "</p>";
                echo '<br><br><form action="insertOrderItem.php" method="post">';
                echo '<input type="hidden" name="orderKey" value="' . $maxKey . '">';
                echo '<input type="hidden" name="locationKey" value="' . $formfield['ffLocationKey'] . '">';
                echo '<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Enter Order Items">';
                echo '</form>';
                $showform = 0;
            }
            catch(PDOException $e)
            {
                echo 'ERROR!!!' .$e->getMessage();
                exit();
            }
        }
    }

if ($visible == 1 && $showform == 1)
{
?>
    <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" name="theform">
        <fieldset><legend>Order Information</legend>
            <table border>
                <tr>
                    <th><label for="custKey">Customer:</label></th>
                    <td><select name="custKey" id="custKey">
                    <option value = "">Please Select a Customer</option>
                    <?php while ($rowc = $resultc->fetch() )
                        {
                        echo '<option value="'. $rowc['dbCustKey'] . '">' . $rowc['dbCustLast'] . '</option>';
                        }
                    ?>
                    </select>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th><label for="tableKey">Table:</label></th>
                    <td><select name="tableKey" id="tableKey">
                    <option value = "">Please Select a Table</option>
                    <?php while ($rowt = $resultt->fetch() )
                        {
                        echo '<option value="'. $rowt['dbTableKey'] . '">' . $rowt['dbTableKey'] . '</option>';
                        }
                    ?>
                    </select>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th><label for="staffKey">Employee:</label></th>
                    <td><select name="staffKey" id="staffKey">
                    <option value = "">Please Select an Employee</option>
                    <?php 
                        while ($rows = $results->fetch() )
                        {
                            if($_SESSION['userid'] == $rows['dbStaffKey']) {
                                $selected = 'selected';
                            } else {
                                $selected = '';
                            }

                        echo '<option value="'. $rows['dbStaffKey'] . '" ' . $selected . '>' . $rows['dbStaffLast'] . '</option>';
                        }
                    ?>
                    </select>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th><label for="locationKey">Location:</label></th>
                    <td><select name="locationKey" id="locationKey">
                    <option value = "">Please Select an Location</option>
                    <?php 
                        while ($rowl = $resultl->fetch() )
                        {   
                        echo '<option value="'. $rowl['dbLocationKey'] . '" ' . $selected . '>' . $rowl['dbLocationCity'] . '</option>';
                        }
                    ?>
                    </select>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Pick a Delivery Type:</th>
                    <td><input type="radio" name="orderPickup" id="orderPickup" 
                                value=1 <?php echo ' checked';?> />
                        <label for="pickup">Pickup</label>
                        <input type="radio" name="orderPickup" id="orderPickup" 
                                value=0 />
                                <label for="inHouse">In-House</label>
                        </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                        <th><label for="orderDate">Entry Date:</label></th>
                        <td><input type="date" name="orderDate" id="orderDate" value="<?php if( isset($formfield['ffOrderDate'])){echo $formfield['ffOrderDate'];}?>" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                        <th><label for="orderTime">Entry Time:</label></th>
                        <td><input type="time" name="orderTime" id="orderTime" value="<?php if( isset($formfield['ffOrderTime'])){echo $formfield['ffOrderTime'];}?>" /></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <input type="submit" name = "thesubmit" value="Enter">
        </fieldset>
    </form>
    <br><br>    
<?php
}
include_once 'footer.php';
?>
```

**insertOrderItem.php**

```
<?php
$pagetitle = 'Insert Order Items';
require_once 'header.php';
require_once 'connect.php';


$formfield['ffOrderKey'] = $_POST['orderKey'];
$formfield['ffProdKey'] = $_POST['prodKey'];
$formfield['ffProdPrice'] = $_POST['prodPrice'];
$formfield['ffProdServing'] = $_POST['prodServing'];
$formfield['ffLocationKey'] = $_POST['locationKey'];

$sqlselectc = "SELECT * FROM theCategories";
$resultc = $db->prepare($sqlselectc);
$resultc->execute();

$sqlselecti = "SELECT * FROM theInventory";
$resulti = $db->prepare($sqlselecti);
$resulti->execute();

if (isset($_POST['OIEnter'])) {
    $rowi = $resulti->fetch();
    $invRem = $rowi['dbInventoryAmt'] - $formfield['ffProdServing'];
    $sqlinsert = 'INSERT INTO theOrderItems (dbOrderKey, dbProdKey, dbProdPrice)
                    VALUES (:bvOrderKey, :bvProdKey, :bvProdPrice)';

                    $stmtinsert = $db->prepare($sqlinsert);
                    $stmtinsert->bindValue(':bvOrderKey', $formfield['ffOrderKey']);
                    $stmtinsert->bindValue(':bvProdKey', $formfield['ffProdKey']);
                    $stmtinsert->bindValue(':bvProdPrice', $formfield['ffProdPrice']);
                    $stmtinsert->execute();

    $sqlupdate = "UPDATE theInventory 
                    SET dbInventoryAmt = :bvInventoryAmt
                    WHERE dbLocationKey = :bvLocationKey 
                    AND dbProdKey = :bvProdKey";
    $stmtupdate = $db->prepare($sqlupdate);
    $stmtupdate->bindValue(':bvInventoryAmt', $invRem);
    $stmtupdate->bindValue(':bvLocationKey', $formfield['ffLocationKey']);
    $stmtupdate->bindValue(':bvProdKey', $formfield['ffProdKey']);
    $stmtupdate->execute();

}

if (isset($_POST['DeleteItem'])) {
    $sqldelete = "DELETE FROM theOrderItems WHERE dbOrderItemKey = :bvOrderItemKey";
    $stmtdelete = $db->prepare($sqldelete);
    $stmtdelete->bindValue(':bvOrderItemKey', $_POST['orderItemKey']);
    $stmtdelete->execute();
}

if (isset($_POST['UpdateItem'])) {
    $formfield['ffProdPrice'] = trim($_POST['newProdPrice']);
    $formfield['ffOrderNotes'] = trim($_POST['newOrderNote']);
    $sqlupdateoi = 'UPDATE theOrderItems
                    SET dbProdPrice = :bvProdPrice,
                        dbOrderNotes = :bvOrderNotes
                        WHERE dbOrderItemKey = :bvOrderItemKey';
    $stmtupdateoi = $db->prepare($sqlupdateoi);
    $stmtupdateoi->bindValue(':bvOrderItemKey', $_POST['orderItemKey']);
    $stmtupdateoi->bindValue(':bvProdPrice', $formfield['ffProdPrice']);
    $stmtupdateoi->bindValue(':bvOrderNotes', $formfield['ffOrderNotes']);
    $stmtupdateoi->execute();   
}   

$sqlselecto = 'SELECT theOrderItems.*, theProducts.dbProdName, theProducts.dbProdServing, theCategories.*
                FROM theOrderItems, theProducts, theCategories
                WHERE theOrderItems.dbProdKey = theProducts.dbProdKey
                AND theProducts.dbCatKey = theCategories.dbCatKey
                AND theOrderItems.dbOrderKey = :bvOrderKey';
$resulto = $db->prepare($sqlselecto);
$resulto->bindValue(':bvOrderKey', $formfield['ffOrderKey']);
$resulto->execute();

if($visible == 1 && ($_SESSION['userpermit'] == 1 || $_SESSION['userpermit'] == 3 || $_SESSION['userpermit'] == 4))
{   
?>

<fieldset><legend><b>Enter Items for Order Number: <?php echo $formfield['ffOrderKey']; ?></b></legend>
<table border>
    <?php
        $counter = 0;
        echo '<tr><b>';
        while ($rowc = $resultc->fetch()){
            if ($counter == 2){
                echo '</tr><tr>';
                $counter = 0;
            }
            $counter++;
            echo '<th valign = "middle" align = "center">' . $rowc['dbCatName'] . '<br> <table border>';
            $sqlselectp = "SELECT * FROM theProducts WHERE dbCatKey = :bvCatKey";
            $resultp = $db->prepare($sqlselectp);
            $resultp->bindValue(':bvCatKey', $rowc['dbCatKey']);
            $resultp->execute();
            while ($rowp = $resultp->fetch()){
                echo '<td>';
                echo '<form action = "' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '" method = "post">';
                echo '<input type = "hidden" name = "orderKey" value = "' . $formfield['ffOrderKey'] . '">';
                echo '<input type = "hidden" name = "prodKey" value = "' . $rowp['dbProdKey'] . '">';
                echo '<input type = "hidden" name = "prodPrice" value = "' . $rowp['dbProdPrice'] . '">';
                echo '<input type = "hidden" name = "prodServing" value = "'. $rowp['dbProdServing'] . '">';
                echo '<input type = "submit" id="order" name = "OIEnter" value = "' . $rowp['dbProdName'] . '">';
                echo '</form>';
                echo '</td>';
            }
            echo '</table></th>';   
        }
        echo '</tr>';
    ?>
    </table>
</table>
</fieldset>
<br><br>
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<table border>
    <tr>
        <th>Item</th>
        <th>Category</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Serving Size</th>
        <th>Price</th>
        <th>Notes</th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
    <?php
        $ordertotal = 0;
        while ($rowo = $resulto->fetch()){
            $ordertotal = $ordertotal + $rowo['dbProdPrice'];
            echo '<tr><td>' . $rowo['dbProdName'] 
                    . '</td><td>' . $rowo['dbCatName'] 
                    . '</td><td>' . $rowo['dbProdDesc'] 
                    . '</td><td>' . $rowo['dbProdServing'] 
                    . '</td><td>' . $rowo['dbProdPrice'] 
                    . '</td><td>' . $rowo['dbOrderNotes'] 
                    . '<td>';

            echo '<form action = "' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '" method = "post">';
            echo '<input type = "hidden" name = "orderKey" value = "' . $formfield['ffOrderKey'] . '">';
            echo '<input type = "hidden" name = "orderItemKey" value = "' . $rowo['dbOrderItemKey'] . '">';
            echo '<input type = "submit" name = "NoteEntry" value = "Update">';
            echo '</form></td><td>';

            echo '<form action = "' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '" method = "post">';
            echo '<input type = "hidden" name = "orderKey" value = "' . $formfield['ffOrderKey'] . '">';
            echo '<input type = "hidden" name = "orderItemKey" value = "' . $rowo['dbOrderItemKey'] . '">';
            echo '<input type = "submit" name = "DeleteItem" value = "Delete">';
            echo '</form></td></tr>';

        }
        echo '<tr><th></th><th></th><th>Total</th><th>' . $ordertotal . '</th><th></th><th></th><th></th></tr>';
    ?>
    </table>
    <?php
        if(isset($_POST['NoteEntry'])){
            $sqlselectoi = 'SELECT theOrderItems.*, theProducts.dbProdName
                FROM theOrderItems, theProducts
                WHERE theOrderItems.dbProdKey = theProducts.dbProdKey
                AND theOrderItems.dbOrderItemKey = :bvOrderItemKey';
            $resultoi = $db->prepare($sqlselectoi);
            $resultoi->bindValue(':bvOrderItemKey', $_POST['orderItemKey']);
            $resultoi->execute();
            $rowoi = $resultoi->fetch();

            echo '</td><td>';

            echo '<form action = "' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '" method = "post">';
            echo '<table>';
            echo '<tr><td>Price: <input type="text" name = "newProdPrice" value = "' . 
                    $rowoi['dbProdPrice'] . '"></td></tr>';
            echo '<tr><td>Notes: <input type="text" name = "newOrderNote" value = "' . 
                    $rowoi['dbOrderNotes'] . '"></td></tr>';
            echo '<tr><td>';
            echo '<input type = "hidden" name = "orderKey" value = "' . $formfield['ffOrderKey'] . '">';
            echo '<input type = "hidden" name = "orderItemKey" value = "' . $rowoi['dbOrderItemKey'] . '">';
            echo '<input type = "submit" name = "UpdateItem" value = Update Item">';
            echo '</td></tr></table>';
        }
    ?>
    </td></tr>
    </table>
    <br><br>
<?php
echo '<form action = "completeorder.php" method = "post">';
echo '<input type = "hidden" name = "orderKey" value = "' . $formfield['ffOrderKey'] . '">';
echo '<input type = "submit" name = "CompleteOrder" value = "Complete Order">';
echo '</form>';
}
include_once 'footer.php';
?>
```

Comment: Why aren't you using auto-increment for `dbOrderKey`?

Comment: I don't understand what you're doing with `$sqlselecti`. There's no `WHERE` clause, so this selects *all* rows from `theInventory`. Then you fetch a single row from it, so this is just some random row from the table. Then you're using that row's `dbInventoryAmt` to get the amount for the `UPDATE` statement.

Comment: My guess is what you really want to do is `UPDATE theInventory SET dbInventoryAmt = dbInventoryAmt - :ffProdServing WHERE ...`

Comment: You know `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` is unsafe to use direcly? Because off the cross side scripting vulnerability... Your better off using `action=""` within the form tag making it post to the same url... in html 5 you can even omit the `action=""` completly.

Comment: Barmar, I am using auto-increment in the database. I assume you are asking because of the $maxKey variable, and this is just to ensure the page passes the correct order number to the next page for the order items.

Comment: Also, I should also clarify that 'theInventory' table has a composite key using two foreign keys, 'dbProdKey' from 'theProducts' table and 'dbLocationKey' from 'theLocations' table. Not sure if that's pertinent or not.

Comment: Raymond Nijland, this is just for a school assignment, so security isn't really within the scope of the project. But I appreciate the advice and I'll keep that in mind for the future.

Comment: Barmar, also, I attempted to use `UPDATE theInventory SET dbInventoryAmt = dbInventoryAmt - :ffProdServing WHERE ...` at first, but I didn't have any luck with that, which is why I opted to just store the value in a variable instead. I'm guessing the problem lies elsewhere. 

From your understanding, it doesn't seem like I should have an issue executing both statements from the same button?